# boundedness theorem question

Tags: real-analysis

Use the Boundedness theorem to show that if the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x)$ is not equal to $0$ for all $x ∈ [0,1]$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|>\delta$ for all $x ∈ [0,1]$.

I don't understand what to do here.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous and never zero on $[0,1]$, $1/f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Now apply the boundedness theorem to $1/f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone please edit it if it is wrong in any way or it needs more justification!!

First, let's notice that either $ f(x) > 0 $ or $ f(x) < 0 $ for all $ x \in [0,1] $ (otherwise, since $ f $ is continuous, we can use Darboux property to show that $ f(x) = 0 $ for some $ x \in [0,1]$). We can therefore assume:

$\textbf{Case 1}$: $ f(x) > 0 $. Now, by the mentioned theorem, by continuity we know that $ f $ achieves its extreme points and since $ \forall_{x\in[0,1]} f(x) \neq 0 $, there exists $\delta_1>0$ $ \delta_1 = \inf\limits_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)| = f(x) > 0 $ and $ f(x) \geq \delta_1 > 0 $ In this case $ \delta = \delta_1 $

$\textbf{Case 2}$: Now assume $f(x)<0$. By the boundedness theorem and by continuity, we know that f achieves its extreme points and since $f(x)$ is not equal to $0$ for all $x∈[0,1]$, there exists $\delta_2<0$ such that $\delta_2=\sup f(x)<0$ and $f(x)\leq\sup f(x)<0$. In this case $ |f(x)|= - f(x) >  \delta = -\delta_2> 0 $

Comment: is this correct? can someone tell me please

Comment: Looks about right

Comment: are you serious? have I justified everything? and are you sure my ending is correct? I was really unsure about that, with taking the 'max'.

Comment: Well, you can delete the last line, because you choose $ \delta_1, \delta_2 $ in separate cases ($ f $ can't be smaller and greater than $ 0 $ at the same time). So it's enough to prove that in one case we have some $ \delta_1 $ and in the other one we have $ \delta_2 $

Comment: but I don't understand if the last line is deleted because the question asks you to prove that |f(x)|>delta. don't you have to define what delta is?

Comment: In the first case $ \delta = \delta_1 $ and in the second $ \delta = \delta_2 $

Comment: ok I see. But one more thing, We put f(x) is more or equal to delta, and f(x) is less or equal to delta, but on the question it says abs of f(x) is strictly more than delta....

Comment: so shouldn't we say for each case, delta is > inf, and delta is < sup?

Comment: $|f(x)| > \delta \iff f(x) > \delta \vee f(x) < -\delta$

Comment: You have covered both cases. Actually in your proof $ \delta_2 $ should be smaller than $0$ and $ \delta = -\delta_2 $

Comment: I know but in your answer you said at the end $f(x)\geq\delta>0$ but are we not trying to end up with $f(x)>\delta$?

Comment: can you just edit my answer please because I am SOO confused!!!

Comment: on the last part of each case, for case 1, u put f(x) is greater or equal to delta but in case 2 , u put -f(x) iss less than or equal to delta. why are they different?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's notice that either $ f(x) > 0 $ or $ f(x) < 0 $ for all $ x \in [0,1] $ (otherwise, since $ f $ is continuous, we can use Darboux property to show that $ f(x) = 0 $ for some $ x \in [0,1]$). We can therefore assume $ f(x) > 0 $. Now, by the mentioned theorem, by continuity we know that $ f $ achieves its extreme points and since $ \forall_{x\in[0,1]} f(x) \neq 0 $ we have $ \delta = \inf\limits_{x \in [0,1]} f(x) > 0 $ and $ f(x) \geq \delta > 0 $

Comment: but where does the modulus of f(x) come in?

Comment: Sorry. I assumed $f(x) > 0$. If $ f(x) < 0 $ the proof is the same

Comment: OK this is what I have, using your answer too. I will post it as an answer to my own question cuz I cant post it here since its too long but please someone correct it if it needs correcting!!